# How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test (class file version 58.65535)) on docker

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm using java14 and switch expression on my project. I would like to use docker on my project, so to do that I am using such a dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-14 AS build
COPY . /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean install -DskipTests
RUN cp /home/app/tra-3-processing/target/*.jar /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

To build properly docker image I have added such a plugin to my pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <source>14</source>
                    <target>14</target>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To create docker image I am using such a command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile_processing -t tra3test:latest .
```

After building the image, I use the simplest docker-compose to test the image.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
    tra-3-processing:
      image: tra3test:latest
      container_name: tra-3-processing
      networks:
      - default1

networks:
  default1:
      driver: bridge
```

However, after launching the container, I am receiving the following error:

```
tra-3-processing    | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for com/processing/ProcessingApplication (class file version 58.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

I have reviewed similar threads, but none related to the docker. Thank you very much for any advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `58.65535` version number means that the class that is being loaded was compiled for Java 14 ( major == 58) with preview features ( minor == 65535 ).

When you run the code, you also need to enable preview features using the `--enable-preview` option in the `java` command.

---

Also, note that Java 14 is already "end of life".  You should be using Java 16 at this point, then switch to Java 17 (LTS) as soon as it is released.

Comment: How can I pass --enable-preview? I've tried to pass it as program arguments, for eg. like that: docker run  nameOfImage --enable-preview

Comment: I'm not a Docker expert, but did you try `ENTRYPOINT ["java","--enable-preview", "-jar","/app.jar"]`.  Either way, you need to do it somehow.